# jQuery HasAttribute Selector

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I need to only target selectpickers that have the attribute `multiple="false"` or they dont have the attribute `multiple` at all. I'm trying to avoid `.selectpickers` that have the attribute `multiple="true"`

I added this code, but then all `.selectpicker` without the multiple attribute at all were not targeted when I need them to be.

```
$(".selectpicker[multiple='false']").on("loaded.bs.select", function (e) {

});
```

Comment: please add html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that `multiple="false"` will still set a multi select, as it's the *attribute* itself that matters, not its *value*:

```html
<p>Note how this is still a multiselect event though 'multiple="false"' is set on it</p>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="false">
  <option>Foo bar</option>
  <option>Fizz buzz</option>
</select>
```

With that being said, once you have valid HTML you can just use `.selectpicker:not([multiple])` in the selector, like this:

```js
$('.selectpicker:not([multiple])').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>This one</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Not this one</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="true">
  <option>Or this one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yup thats what it was. Thanks for your help.